# Python(django)....and the db

Tags: django

i have one web application, with postgresql as DB, evrything is fine..now trying to implement one security feature..that my db should be updated or del or any thing has to done through my application only...and admin also...i.e sort to protecting the db..no one change it back end..and through some application....i need some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it mean through your application only? As opposed to changed with direct access to the database?

If that is the case then it is trivial - do not distribute the database password to anyone.
If you need to give access to other applications create separate users/roles for such purpose.

As for django - it provides another layer of security, as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) and you can extend it if it does not fit your bill.

Comment: only my application can do the operations on database......ya thk u...i will try...